# How to pass a value of a clicked link to another page and show it in a span

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

Thought this one will be easy, but it turns out that it's not - at least for me.

I would like to pass a value(string) to another page if my link gets clicked by a user.

Code example:

```
On page one:
<a href="secondPage.php" value="sun" onclick="setWord(this.value)">click me</a>


On page two:
<p> The <span id="passedWord"></span> is shining!</p>


Javascript:
function setWord(x) {
   document.getElementById("passedWord").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Any tips how I can solve my problem?

Comment: `secondPage.php?value=sun` instead in your href? Then use PHP's `$_REQUEST['value']` to extract the "sun" word and insert it like so `<span id="passedWord"><?php $_REQUEST['value'] ?></span>`

Comment: Thanks for response @Dellirium , but it doesn't paste the word in the span! Any other suggestions?

Comment: There are other, more complicated ways, but are really not necessary for this, this is the cleanest most simple solution you can have for communicating values from client to server when changing a page. Actually i prolly made a mistake, in the span put `<?php echo $_REQUEST['value'] ?>`

Comment: i tried this 'print_r($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])' and it puts value=sun in there.
Is 'value=' necessary? Or could i just set href="secondPage.php?sun" ?

Comment: don't use the query string like that, put the `value=sun` and add the `echo` keyword, i forgot to put that one in

Comment: Works! thanks @Dellirium!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
//On page one:
<a href="secondPage.php?value=sun">click me</a>
//On page two:
//you can get the value by using this
<?php
    $value = $_GET["value"];
?>
The <span id="passedWord"><?php echo $value; ?></span> is shining!
```

Comment: You should never blindly output request data into your HTML. At least escape the value first. E.g. `<?php echo htmlentities($value); ?>`

Comment: Yeah that's true that can cause XSS vulnerability, thanks for the addition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. Since i'm not that into php i have to ask: is your solution more efficient than <span><?php echo $_REQUEST['value'] ?><span> ?
regards!

Comment: Yeah in your case i think that's more efficient but in the second page before displaying the value make sure you use <?php echo htmlentities($value); ?> for security reasons.